# innodb_buffer_pool_size with large InnoDB archive table

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

I've been reading a whole ton on various MySQL configurations and I am still a bit unsure regarding my innodb_buffer_pool_size and was hoping someone could help.

I have some large InnoDB tables, the largest being (18gb with some INT columns, two TEXT columns [one being a 'description' which can be large'], and some small VARCHARS - roughly 23m rows). I've got a couple indexes on for the PK, a TINYINT column, a product ID column, and a datetime column.

I'm not doing excessive reading from the table, mostly writing to it and occasionally bringing in chunks of it to Solr.

Anyways, a lot of people keep recommending to make for a large innodb_buffer_pool_size that is around the size of your data. Now I do have a dedicated instance for it but its only something like 2gb of memory or something.

Am I missing something here or is this table just not the typical table they are recommending those types of settings for? Because it seems to me like quite a bit overboard to reach for needing anywhere near that much memory. The Index size on that table is about 1.6Gb.

Thanks for your help - would love to clear up this confusion
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derr.. It ended up being what I had presumed it had to be - you want your innodb_buffer_pool_size to be large enough to contain your InnnoDB indexes..

Comment: could you expand this matter please?